# converting cell dates to datenum and nulls to NaN

Tags: string, matlab, date, cell-array

I download some data from an sql database into a cell of 6000 x 5. I want the 2:end columns to be converted into a datenum. In the four columns some of the dates in the database are NULL (please see below for example of the data I am downloading). I would like these NULL dates to be either NaN or zero.

```
 '100364MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100377MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100394MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100395MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100996MM' 'null'  '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '101005MM' 'null'  '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
```

I have been playing around with the lines below however I get an error message saying DATENUM failed. I'm guessing this is due to the 'null'?

```
 my_dates = zeros(6000, 5)
 my_dates = cellfun(@datenum, data_matrix(:, 2:end));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `datenum` quits with an error as soon as it finds a non-conforming string. So it's difficult to do it in a vectorized manner in your case (see [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310843/2586922), tough).

Here's a quick and dirty solution with `try` and a `for` loop:

First define the data:

```
d = {'100364MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
     '100377MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
     '100394MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
     '100395MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
     '100996MM' 'null'  '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
     '101005MM' 'null'  '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'};
```

Then:

```
result = NaN(size(d));
for n = 1:numel(d)
    try
        result(n) = datenum(d(n));
    end
end
```

This gives

```
result =
         NaN         NaN      729542      729542         NaN
         NaN         NaN      729542      729542         NaN
         NaN         NaN      729542      729542         NaN
         NaN         NaN      729542      729542         NaN
         NaN         NaN      729572      729572         NaN
         NaN         NaN      729572      729572         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Vectorized approach -

```
%// a1 is the input cell array
a1= {
 '100364MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100377MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100394MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100395MM' 'null'  '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-06-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '100996MM' 'null'  '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'
 '101005MM' 'null'  '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' '1997-07-01 00:00:00.0' 'null'}

ind1 = ~strcmp(a1,'null')
a1(~ind1)={NaN}
ind1(:,1)=false

%// Choose one of the following two, as the output format demands
a1(ind1) = num2cell(datenum(a1(ind1))) %// datenum as cells of double
a1(ind1) = cellstr(num2str(datenum(a1(ind1)))) %// datenum as cells of strings
```

Output -

Option 1:

```
a1 = 
    '100364MM'    [NaN]    [729542]    [729542]    [NaN]
    '100377MM'    [NaN]    [729542]    [729542]    [NaN]
    '100394MM'    [NaN]    [729542]    [729542]    [NaN]
    '100395MM'    [NaN]    [729542]    [729542]    [NaN]
    '100996MM'    [NaN]    [729572]    [729572]    [NaN]
    '101005MM'    [NaN]    [729572]    [729572]    [NaN]
```

Option 2:

```
a1 = 
    '100364MM'    [NaN]    '729542'    '729542'    [NaN]
    '100377MM'    [NaN]    '729542'    '729542'    [NaN]
    '100394MM'    [NaN]    '729542'    '729542'    [NaN]
    '100395MM'    [NaN]    '729542'    '729542'    [NaN]
    '100996MM'    [NaN]    '729572'    '729572'    [NaN]
    '101005MM'    [NaN]    '729572'    '729572'    [NaN]
```